# Form Base Authentication not working when I use random Database column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC form base custom authentication using SQL database. I've Column  with `CustomerRole` name.

I am checking Authorization as per following:

### TestController.CS

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public ActionResult AdminPage()
{
    return View();
}
```

### AccountController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(UserModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    // Lets first check if the Model is valid or not
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        using (userDbEntities entities = new userDbEntities())
        {
            string username = model.username;
            string password = model.password;
            // Now if our password was enctypted or hashed we would have          done the
            // same operation on the user entered password here, But for now
            // since the password is in plain text lets just authenticate directly

            bool userValid = entities.Tbl_UserMast.Any(user => user.UserName == username && user.UserPassword == password);

            // User found in the database
            if (userValid)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                 && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
             }
             else
             {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
             }
          }
      }

      // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
      return View(model);
  }
```

So when I go AdminPage Action. It shows me I am not Authorized.
If I change my column name as `Roles`, it is working. But I am not allowed to change column name. Is there any other alternative, where I can use Authorization with same column name

Comment: Have you tried doing `[Authorize(CustomerRole="admin")]` ?

Comment: No actually I don't know about it in depth. I am following tutorials only

Comment: Ok. When I use CustomerRole, It give me error 'System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'CustomerRole'

Comment: can you show implementation of Authorize?

Comment: ok I edited my question

Comment: I think you have to make your own custom authorization filter to fulfill your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Try Custom Authentication Filer
Try this:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.CookiesSupported == true)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
        {
            try
            {
                //let us take out the username now                
                string username = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value).Name;
                string roles = string.Empty;

                using (userDbEntities entities = new userDbEntities())
                {
                    var user = entities.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.username == UserName);

                    roles = user.UserRole;
                }
                //let us extract the roles from our own custom cookie


                //Let us set the Pricipal with our user specific details
                HttpContext.Current.User  = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(
                  new System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity(username, "Forms"), roles.Split(';'));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                //somehting went wrong
            }
        }
    }
}
```